# Customize ng-multiselect-dropdown so we can bind multiple model fields

Tags: angular, npm, angular-material

[image]

How to customize `ng-multiselect-dropdown` control so we can add `CodeField`, It helps me to persist model value while selection?

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Can you elaborate your question a bit?

Comment: ng-multiselect-dropdown have default  bindable property i.e idField and textField. both the field values persisted.  above ask is how to add one more bindable  property "codeField" in the ng-multiselect-dropdown?

CustomerList model 
[ { Id : 1 , Name: 'customer1', Code : 'AD' Department: 'admin'},
{ Id : 2 , Name: 'customer2', Code : 'SA' Department: 'sales'},
{ Id : 3 , Name: 'customer3', Code : 'OR' Department: 'Order'}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

step1 : we can refer below link
https://cuppalabs.github.io/angular2-multiselect-dropdown/#/groupby

step2 :

```
<angular2-multiselect id="CustomerControlId"
                                          [data]="CustomerList"
                                          formControlName="customerControl"
                                          [settings]="MultiSelectSettingsByGroup"
                                          (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
                                          (onDeSelect)="onItemDeSelect($event)"
                                          (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
                                          (onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAll($event)">
                    </angular2-multiselect>
```

step 3: settings

```
 this.MultiSelectSettingsByGroup = {
        singleSelection: false,
        text: "Select Fields",
        selectAllText: 'Select All',
        unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
        searchPlaceholderText: 'Search',
        primaryKey:"Id",
        labelKey:"Name",
        enableSearchFilter: true,
        badgeShowLimit: 5,
        groupBy: "Code"
    };
```

step 4 : load list in CustomerList.

```
CustomerList: DropdownItemExt[] = [];

export class DropdownItemExt {
Id: string;
Code: string;
Name: string;
```

}

step 5 : you can place in Reactive forms 'fb' is formBuilder

```
return this.fb.group({
        customerControl: new FormControl(this.Fsmodel.customers), // model class property , optional for initializing from FsModel
```

step 6 : you can find selected customers

```
this.rcForm.get('customerControl').value as DropdownItemExt[];
```

step 7 : settings configuration is case-sensitive refer steps 3 & 4.